Google TTS pronounciation of "AI"
I find it funny the AI voices from Google Cloud TTS struggle with correct pronounciation of the "AI" acronym. It applies to neural, studio and news voices. I tried to fix it with following SSMLs:
<say-as interpret-as="spell-out">ai</say-as>

and
<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="eɪ.ˈaɪ">ai</phoneme>

Both sound bad in their own ways ;-) I had also tried quoting "AI" which led to even worse results.
How to make Google Cloud TTS pronounce the "AI" acronym correctly? Play.ht, for instance, seems to handle this well out of the box.

Hi @Marcin, Did you try using .... at the beginning and ending of the ssml tags to get the expected output. Try using this  <speak> <say-as interpret-as="spell-out">ai</say-as> </speak>  in this cloud TTS API and let me know if this helped you or not.

Hi @Marcin, I have posted the above comment as answer, if it addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

As commented above, you have to use <speak>....</speak> at the beginning and ending of the ssml tags to get the expected output.
Your SSML tag should be something like this -
<speak> <say-as interpret-as="spell-out">ai</say-as> </speak> .
You can try using the above format in the Cloud TTS API.
